# configuring development eggs in zc.buildout

Tags: python

I am new to zc.buildout and am looking to get started with it. I was looking over the concept of configuring eggs as parts and modules being developed as develop-eggs in the cfg file. I am having trouble figuring out how I should go about configuring an external dependency for my module being developed. I figured that the module I am writing goes in as a develop-egg in the buildout.cfg file. My module also depends on another external module say ABC. The ABC module is listed in my module's setup.py as a dependency. But should I also list it as a part in my buildout.cfg file.

I am really having trouble figuring out what external dependencies go under parts in the buildout.cfg or under dependencies in the my module's setup.py. The way I think about it, any external dependency being listed should be needed by my module, else it is not getting used and shouldn't go in the configuration at all (considering buildout use cases for setting up dev environments). So, what are the external dependencies that need to be listed as parts in the buildout.cfg file?

Thank You,
Vish

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the mr.developer extension for zc.buildout:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer

The auto-checkout option can be used to perform checkout of the packages from a repository that are actually needed for development. The dependencies specs in your setup.py file have basically nothing to do with deployment vs. development.

Comment: Hi Andreas,

Thank you for the link to mr.developer. But I think my question is a little different. If I am working on a module and it depends on another module on PyPI say oauth, should I list oauth both in the setup.py for my module and also in the parts section of buildout.cfg? Should I have em in both places? Because when buildout runs, doesn't it does bring down the dependencies for my modules(from setup.py) also and also the parts in buildout.cfg?

Thank You,
Vish

Comment: Module listed as dependency in setup.py usually don't need to be listed in zc.buildout.

Comment: @Blackmoon, when I mentioned the dependency package in the setup.py install_requires list, it doesn't seem to get installed and while trying to import that module I get an error. But with adding the dependency in buildout.cfg, it does work fine. What could be the issue here?